# PHP - Switch Case with Exceptions

Tags: php, switch-statement

I am wondering if I should include `break` in my switch even if a case is throwing an exception.

```
switch ($key) {
    case self::ABC:
    case self::CBA:
        if (!is_string($key)) {
            throw new Exception('Well.. this should be a string my friend');
        }
        break;
}
```

Am I even getting to the break? I do not think so, so why should I include it? Does it makes sense?

Comment: Well what if the exception isn't thrown, ie. the key is a string?

Comment: It is just for validating an array. If the param is a string it will just go threw and will return true later in my method.

Comment: Is that the whole `switch` statement or just an abbreviated example.

Comment: If the exception was thrown, your code will not reach the break, but if key is a string, then the code reaches the break.

Comment: It's redundant, unless `self::ABC/self::CBA:` is a number value.  If these are `foo` and `bar` well `$key` is obviously a string.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte well... that was actually the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this is just an academic question (meaning you just want to know something, regardless of its real world use).  Using constants in a switch generally means by the time the type is checked you should have a pretty good Idea of what the value is and is not.  There are some exceptions because of the  loosely typed nature of PHP and switches implied use of `==` not `===`.  If that is a possibility I would check it outside/before the switch. Generally you shouldn't re-type a variable.  You can in PHP but that doesn't mean you should.  So what I mean is if its a string it should always be 1.

Answer (score 1):

If `self::CBA` is a string, then the exception won't be thrown and your code will reach to break. If that `case` is the last case in your switch, then break may not be needed as the switch will end anyways, but it is better to just add `break` instead of not adding it, it's one line of code that can save you a lot of trouble from executing codes that were not meant to be executed. I know this the hard way.

By adding break to all cases, you can rearrange the cases without any problems in the future and you would also get into the habit of writing break every time you write a switch statement (it's a good habit). I hope it answers your question.